# Weird graph in PyPlot

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, graph

I'm trying to declare a method for plotting the keys and values from a dictionary. The dictionary represents the amount of scientific works done each year in a certain period.

Inside my main class, I've declared it like this, sci_prod being the dictionary:

```
def graphic(self, sci_prod):
    self.sci_prod = sci_prod
    x = list(sci_prod.keys())
    y = list(sci_prod.values())
    #plt.plot(x, y)
    #plt.xlabel("Year", fontsize=15)
    #plt.ylabel("Number of Completed Works", fontsize=15)
    #plt.show()
```

But I keep getting a very weird graph that somehow touches on the values, but with strange forms in between. Why is that?

Comment: This question is not very well expanded, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: There are several ways the code shown in the question would produce something "weird"; and equally there are several ways it would produce something not so "weird". All depends on the input - which you keep secret here.

Comment: I assume it's because you're using a dict which is unordered with a line plot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This ought to do it, in the absence of your data or seeing what the weird plot looks like to confirm

```
def graphic(self, sci_prod):
    self.sci_prod = sci_prod
    x = sorted(list(sci_prod.keys()))
    y = [sci_prod[k] for k in x]
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.xlabel("Year", fontsize=15)
    plt.ylabel("Number of Completed Works", fontsize=15)
    plt.show()
```